# How do I fix the span to have img as background?

Tags: html

[image]

Now it was all fine when I set the picture as background `background: url(http://simplisafe.com/files/images/icons/check_mark.png)`
and I got the desired output. BUT when the user sets the font-size to something else, the check mark picture remains the same size (the font size setting indirectly changes the size of the spans and divs too). **Basically I want the picture scalable and in the background behind the number.**

I already tried background-size, but it doesn't work.

```
<html>
<head><style type="text/css">
html {overflow-y:hidden;}
body {overflow-y:auto;}
   input { margin: 3px 0; vertical-align: middle; } 
   .box { border: 1px solid #aeaeae; padding: 3px; width: 6em; text-align: left; text-indent:.3em;    }
    .innerbox { width: 4em; text-align: left;}

#page-background {position: absolute; z-index:-1;}
#content {position: relative;}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<span class="box" id="1"><nobr>
 <span id="page-background"><img  src="http://simplisafe.com/files/images/icons/check_mark.png" />0&nbsp;
  <span class="innerbox" id="content">
     <DIV id="P_0" align="left" > 
     <input style="width:100%; border:1px solid #B4B4B4; font-size:12px" type="text" id="1" />
     </DIV>
   </span>
</span>                          
</nobr></span>
<body>
</html>
```

I added both `#page-background` and `#content` to make a checkmark img the background of the span but it just messes up my span.
I tested the `#page-background` and `#content` on 2 overlapping spans and it works just fine, when I tried on add it to my existing code, the `position: absolute` messes up the span (see picture).

**How can I fix this or is there another way to do this?**

Comment: You're not supposed to have a `div` inside a `span`...

Comment: @icktoofay: It's not my code, I'm just maintaining it... so... why not? It works fine before I tried the img stuff.

Comment: `<span>` and `<div>` are both generic elements intended for grouping, but `<span>` is for inline use (ie text). I can't really understand your problem, could you explain how you want it to look?

Comment: @nhilae: I added additional stuff to the question. (and posted a picture of how I want it to look like)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your html is so wrong...

Since it seems you can't change the html (sic), you can use [this](http://www.jsfiddle.net/DMvcu/).

---

**EDIT:** or [this](http://www.jsfiddle.net/DMvcu/2/) (using position: absolute) 
You'd better change your html anyway, b/c you must use `padding` in this case and I'm not sure that :

1. It'll be the same effect on every browser (tested on chrome)
2. Changing size (by some script you don't give... so we can't test) won't stretch it.

---

Anyway, if you can change it, it'll lighten things up like [this](http://www.jsfiddle.net/DMvcu/1/)

Comment: When the text size is adjusted (via some function which I did not make), everything including the boxes change in size except the picture. I'm basically looking for a way to make the background/picture scalable.

Comment: And yeah, I'm allowed to make minimal changes but some other code will access the outer span and the inner div.. I can't change that part.

Comment: The script is in delphi (I was thinking of maybe adding to it so I can resize the picture too). I was going for something like this http://bit.ly/a6m5td , but instead of the window being the basis of the size of the background the span size will be the basis.

Comment: Then... if you got your answer, go ahead ò_o

Comment: Errr..that's the problem.. the code works on a particular case but it messes up the span and I can't pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Examined your edit again and tweaked it a bit and it resizes the picture now, so thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Or you could do it much simpler:

```
.box{
   display:inline-block;
   border:1px solid #aeaeae; 
   padding:9px 5px 9px 38px;
   background:url('http://simplisafe.com/files/images/icons/check_mark.png') no-repeat;
}

<div class="box">
    0 <input type="text"/>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gpQ5f/

Comment: I stated I tried using the background... but the size is the  problem. When the element size changes the background size remains the same.

Comment: what do you mean background size remains the same? Do you want to resize the image? Use javascript, background in your example will have the exact size all the time.

Comment: I want something like this - http://bit.ly/a6m5td but instead of the window being the basis of the picture/background size, it should be the span.

Comment: i can tell from your example - it's not the way to do it. First you put block inside inline elements, then you want to stretch background image, what's next, blink or marquee?

Comment: @negative: Well, it's a client request and I can't exactly do anything about it. Don't worry about blink or marquee, I don't think the client is THAT unreasonable.